# Ableton Live: Zoom out farther than current bounds?

Tags: ableton-live

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a quick way to zoom out: farther than the current bounds.

Sometimes I want to place a clip past the current view, and it's frustrating that the zoom caps out unlike Audacity and other DAWs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can quickly **drag up the left number 1** (or loop start or length)

[image]

then **drag up the seekbar** (zoom out)

[image]

---

This is similar to the MIDI Notes panel: Length section, which zooms at the same time

[image]

Comment: ♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡